# Calling a variable from a new Tkinter window widget

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter, widget

I have a search function--

```
def searchref (event=None):
   
    ref = searchreftxt.get()

    data=[]
    with open("data.csv") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)
    col = [x[0] for x in data]
    print("You searched for:" , ref)
    if ref in col:
        for x in range(0,len(data)):
            if ref == data[x][0]:
                print(data[x])
                label2.configure(text=data[x])
    else:
        print ("Reference doesn't exist")
```

and when I open a new tkinter toplayer window from a menu command (a different function)
the searchref function cannot get the Entry data...it says it is undefined.

```
def open_searchwindow():
    searchwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    searchwindow.config(menu=menubar)
    searchwindow.title("Search")
    searchwindow.geometry ('350x200+1090+50')

    srchreflbl = tk.Label(searchwindow, text="Reference:", padx=5, pady=5, font=("arial", 12))
    srchreflbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

    searchreftxt = tk.Entry(searchwindow, width=14)
    searchreftxt.grid(column=1, row=0)
    searchreftxt.focus()
    searchreftxt.bind('<Return>', searchref)

    btnref = tk.Button(searchwindow, text="Search", command=searchref)
    btnref.grid(column=2, row=0)
```

Been searching everywhere for a solution for the last couple of days. What do I want to do with this?

Gratefully yours

Comment: `searchreftxt` is a local variable and can only be accessed from `open_searchwindow`. To make it a global variable (accessible to the rest of the program), add `global searchreftxt` to the first line of `open_searchwindow`.

Comment: I had read elsewhere it is best to avoid using global variables, though that certainly does the trick.....

Comment: If you really wanted to avoid global variables, you could pass `searchreftxt` as an argument to `searchref`, or use an object oriented approach. Both of these would work, but a global variable is the most straightforward.